# Regex: format log message into HTML codes

Tags: php, regex

I have a log file. I want to separate each log into two groups so I can wrap them with some HTML tags.

```
[25-Nov-2020 11:49:39 UTC] [Error] some error message.
{"good":"14"}
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/Sites/test/test.php(180)
[25-Nov-2020 11:49:39 UTC] [Info] some info message.
Array(
  some message
)

Stack trace:
#0 /Users/Sites/test/test.php(10)
#1 /Users/Sites/test/test.php(40)
#2 /Users/Sites/test/test.php(1500)
```

Final expected result

```
<details>
    <summary>[25-Nov-2020 07:24:51 UTC] [Error] some error message.</summary>
    <pre>{"good":"14"}
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/Sites/test/test.php(180)</pre>
</details>
<details>
    <summary>[25-Nov-2020 07:24:51 UTC] [Info] some info message.</summary>
    <pre>Array(
  some message
)

Stack trace:
#0 /Users/Sites/test/test.php(10)
#1 /Users/Sites/test/test.php(40)
#2 /Users/Sites/test/test.php(1500)</pre>
</details>
```

So far, I have tried `(?(?=\[.* UTC\].*)(\[.*)|(.*))` in this [site](https://regex101.com/r/47PScf/2) but I can't get two groups for each log. I get many groups. I think if I can get each log into two groups, I can add necessary tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 2 capture groups, and match the UTC part between the square brackets without using an if clause or an alternation.

In the replacement use group 1 and group 2.

```
^(\[[^][]*\hUTC].*)((?:\R(?!\[).*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\[[^][]*\hUTC].*` Match `[`, then `UTC]` and the rest of the line
- `)` Close group 1
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:\R(?!\[).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with `[`
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a6yY7D/1)